# Interpreting $s$ vs. $t$ graphs

Tags: kinematics

While reading Arnold Arons book Teaching Introductory Physics, I came across this paragraph (Part 1, page 29, emphasis in original):

> "An especially important exercise with graphs is one in which students are asked to give verbal interpretations of various *lengths* in an $s$ versus $t$ diagram. For example, they should be able to identify a length parallel to the $s$-axis as representing a *change* in position. Similarly, they should be able to identify a length parallel to the $t$-axis as a time *interval*. A final very important contrast is provided by asking about the interpretation of a *diagonal* segment in an $s$ versus $t$ diagram. The majority of students do not initially have the courage of conviction to say that such a segment has no physical interpretation; they accord some spurious interpretation, most frequently a distance traversed by the body."

Can someone elaborate on meaning of the last sentence?

Comment: To say that a graph of distance vs time has no physical meaning just sounds downright ridiculous. I strongly suggest getting a better textbook!

Comment: The slope of a straight diagonal line on a s vs. t graph is the velocity of the object.  Also, I agree with @AlbertusMagnus ... the author of the book that you are using doesn't appear to know much physics.

Comment: And if he does know physics then he is likely to be one of those authors who are better at confusing than at enlightening.

Comment: Arnold Arons was one of the pioneers in physics education. This is one of the better textbooks out there, which looks at pedagogical aspects of teaching physics as well and not only about the "mechanics" of doing it as several texts do. I was confused about this paragraph hence asked here (but it seems that was my mistake). Have a look at the book before dissing on it and the author. Here is a review by Redish https://www.physics.umd.edu/icpe/newsletters/n34/Book.htm and about Arons https://pubs.aip.org/physicstoday/article/54/9/76/951501/Arnold-Boris-Arons

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for by way of elaboration.  I think the point of this sentence is really exactly what it says: the students think there's a meaning to the thing, and so they just grasp at straws trying to come up with something rather than using some base-level of understanding to *infer* what it might or might not mean.  As an aside, the only interpretation of that diagonal might be that its slope is an average velocity.  However, the diagonal *itself* *almost* represents an interval in \emph{space-time}, except that it's length is wrong, and so it's physically meaningless.

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus. He's not saying that a graph of distance vs time has no physical meaning; he's saying that a diagonal interval *itself* doesn't have an intrinsic meaning (it's *almost* a space-time interval, except that the length is wrong, so it doesn't really mean anything). If the endpoints of the interval happen to coincide with points on the graph, then the *slope* of the line could be interpreted as an average velocity, but the *thing itself* doesn't have meaning.

Comment: can we an $s$ vs $t$ graph of which he speaks? Is this paragraph about "physics doesn't care about your coordinates", or does the graph lack scale, in which case a diagonal segment represents motion at some constant velocity. Of course, Galileo taught us that coordinates don't mean anything, so the only meaning a straight segment has is the the object was motionless in some coordinate system for some period of time. If those coordinates are arbitrary (not Cartesian, or maybe not even static) then it really means _nothing_ .

Comment: If this is considered good pedagogy then I’m glad I got bad pedagogy.

Comment: @march Those were my exact thoughts, and I started to write it out, however, it didn't seem like it was the kind of thing to explain to a beginner...But maybe I am underestimating beginners.